# FullCalendar v4 dynamically set a calendar’s height

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

In my Laravel App, I've made .js file `fullCalendar.js' and this is inside of it:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import rrulePlugin from '@fullcalendar/rrule';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import momentPlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment';
import allLocales from '@fullcalendar/core/locales-all';

import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/list/main.css';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, rrulePlugin, interactionPlugin, momentPlugin ],
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    locales: allLocales,
    locale: 'sr-ME',
    timezone : 'local',
    editable: true,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: {
        url: '/eventi',
        failure: function() {
            document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
        }
    },
    loading: function(bool) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = bool ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

And in my blade `calendar.blade.php` I have included that file 
`<script src="{{ asset('js/fullCalendar.js') }}" ></script>` 
and I have `<div>` with id `id="calendar"` And I can see my calendar and it's working without any problems.
If I want to dynamically set a calendar’s height in certain `blade.php` (view) with this line that I saw on their website 
`calendar.setOption('height', 700);`
I get an error saying this: **Uncaught TypeError: calendar.setOption is not a function**
I tried putting in when document is ready or before that or even adding event listener for `DOMContentLoaded` but the error is still there. After every change in my .js file I run following command `npm run dev` to compile it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the setOption in your code? I don't see it

Comment: In my blade where I included my `fullCalendar.js` I tried putting it inside document ready or outside, but it's not working.

Comment: Well `var calendar` only exists within the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {` block it's declared in. So either you have to use `setOption` somewhere within there, or you have to make `calendar` global, or you have to find some other way of passing a reference to `calendar` to the necessary place(s) in your code.

Comment: It worked. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 2):

As @ADyson said in his comment, I just need to declare calendar as global. Once I did it I can use `calendar.setOption('height', 700);` and other calendar functions.